# How do I Animate Linear Layout Background Gradient Progmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, gradient

How do I change the background image of a LinearLayout progmatically?

What I am trying to achieve is to animate the tranisiton between two gradients as shown below to add to the background of a `LinearLayout`.

[image]

I have two gradients that i built progrmatically,

```
val gradient = GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
    intArrayOf(
        Color.argb(255, Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256)),
        Color.argb(255, Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256)),
    )
)

val gradient2 = GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT,
    intArrayOf(
        Color.argb(255, Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256)),
        Color.argb(255, Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256), Random().nextInt(256)),
    )
)
```

I would like to animate the background of a linear layout as transition from one gradient to another. I know with xml we can animate using `animation-list`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:duration="5000"
          android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_start"/>

    <item android:duration="5000"
          android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_center"/>

    <item android:duration="5000"
          android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_end"/>

</animation-list>
```

but I am looking for a progmatic way with kotlin code, also I know there existed this project https://github.com/dynamitechetan/Flowing-Gradient which is not supported as of now. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that programmatically using AnimationDrawable(),

```
val animDrawable = AnimationDrawable()
animDrawable.isOneShot = false  //Is set false make animation run infinitely 

val gradient = GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
    intArrayOf(
        Color.argb(255, Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256)),
        Color.argb(255, Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256))
    )
)

val gradient2 = GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT,
    intArrayOf(
        Color.argb(255, Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256)),
        Color.argb(255, Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256))
    )
)

animDrawable.addFrame(gradient,3000) // Added gradientDrawable to animDrawable
animDrawable.addFrame(gradient2,1500)

animDrawable.apply {  //To make it more smooth setting enter fade duration and exit fade duration
                setEnterFadeDuration(1000)
                setExitFadeDuration(1000)
            }

linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(animDrawable) //set animDrawable to linearLayouot background
animDrawable.start() //start Animation
```

You can change duration according to your requirement to make it look more interesting.